# Not able to run the project using yarn

Tags: reactjs, yarn-lock.json

I am trying to run this project using the yarn , but its showing :

**yarn install v1.22.19
error An unexpected error occurred: "Invalid value type 141:0 in /media/krushna/Data/Placement/Aircall/aircall/yarn.lock".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/media/krushna/Data/Placement/Aircall/aircall/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.**

this is my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "frontend-hiring-challenge",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Leap test",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "",
  "author": "",
  "license": "",
  "private": false,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "6.26.*",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.*",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.*",
    "css-loader": "2.1.*",
    "html-loader": "0.5.*",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.*",
    "style-loader": "0.23.*",
    "webpack": "4.29.*",
    "webpack-cli": "3.2.*",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.1.*"
  }
}
```

repo link :https://github.com/krishmk1009/aircall

Comment: Can you provide the yarn-error.log file ?